# Direct link to browser with Notification

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

This is a simple logic, but i can't figure it out.

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
     if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject],
     let alert1 = aps["alert"] as? String,
     let content1 = aps["content-available"] as? String,
     let link1 = aps["links"] as? String {
        if link1 == "" {
           //Ok pressed do nothing
          }else{
           // after OK pressed. jump to page "example" http://www.google.com
          }
    }
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
}
```

I have a push from my web. It contain 2 type of push :

1. I push notify without link
2. I push with link inside. (if i press the notify ill jump to
   the page example : http://www.google.com)

if without link, "link1" will be empty and just showed up message. after that nothing.

[image: link = empty. just show message]

However if i push with a link, How can i jump to the browser after i pressed the ok button ?

[image: Got link inside]

**Added** Full code if you want to see http://pastebin.com/cFYqLqs7

**ASK** Should i use Deep linking in this case ? because the link can change depend on what i push.

Comment: any suggestion please ? @Sandy Chapman

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL: